# Trying the else if statement?

Tags: if-statement

Hi im a noob im having a problem figuring out how to use the else if

heres what i got so far it dosent work right for me..

```
    var name = "mom"
var name = "dad"
name = prompt("what is your name?");
if (name = "mom"){ 
     alert("Hello Mother." );
} if (name = "dad"){
     alert("hello father." );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check out [ask]. Particularly, note that "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of a problem. Provide some sample inputs and expected outputs, as well as current outputs to make the issue as clear as possible to potential answerers.

Comment: I think it is javascript, but you didn't even say what programming language this is.

Comment: try using an == when comparing name variable instead of a single =

Comment: to compare 2 values you use ==

Comment: Please include the error code and programming language you're using to help get the best answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper tags on your question, otherwise it's not clear what language you're in.  But it looks like JavaScript, so try this:

```
var name = prompt("what is your name?");
if (name == "mom"){ 
     alert("Hello Mother.");
} else if (name == "dad"){
     alert("hello father.");
} else {
     alert("hello stranger.");
}
```

Note that you need `==` to compare values.  A single `=` is an assignment.  If such distinctions are not clear to you, please consider following one of the many JavaScript tutorials available on the web.

Comment: They were copy pastes from the original :) Removed now.

Comment: could i use null wor the third line so that when someone types nothing in or an unknown name it alerts says hello stranger

Answer (score 0):

this is not proper way to do, but you can use different variables

```
var mom ="mom";
var dad = "dad";
var name = prompt("What is your name");
if(name == mom) {
   alert("Hello mother.");
} else {
  alert("Hello father.")
}
```

Comment: What if I enter `"foo"` and I'm not father?

Comment: For if or if else statement you first have to decide what is your expected output would be. Then you must structure the if or if else blocks...You check some condition(s) and if the returned true you execute farther statement(s) or returned false you may execute statement(s) farther.

in above example, entering foo will alert Hello farther., because name is not equal to foo and the condition was false.

Comment: No, but your if statement right now assumes I'm father it I'm not mother. That's wrong

Comment: yes that is the whole point .We did not verify foo or any unwanted word yet by if statement and alert what should be result for that specific input. if enter foo and i am not father i have to check that if i entered foo and am i father.like
===============
var mom ="mom";
var dad = "dad";
var name = prompt("What is your name");
if(name == mom) {
   alert("Hello mother.");
} else  if(name == dad){
  alert("Hello father.")
} else {

  alert("you have entered  "+name+"  not mom, not father");

}
=========================

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want... (JavaScript)

```
 var name = prompt("what is your name?");

  if(name == "mom"){
   alert ("Hello Mother." ); 
   } 

  else if(name == "dad"){ 
  alert ("hello father." ); 
  }
   else{
  alert ("Your name is not recognised");
     }
```

Comment: could i use null wor the third line so that when someone types nothing in or an unknown name it alerts says hello stranger

Comment: @scott You could probably change the **else** comment to _hello stranger_  . you would get the **hello stranger** for **null** input